# Trying to write a norm inside a norm:

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, is it correct the following operation?

$$ || xy^H y|| = || x || y||^2 ||= ||x|| ||y||^2$$

since $y^H y = \langle y,y \rangle = ||y||^2 $.

Comment: If you mean $r=y$ then it's ok. After the edit it's ok :-).

Comment: Provided you write  $x y^H y$ as  $x(y^Hy) $ and not as  $(xy^H)y$. We can have  $(xy^H)=0 $ with $ x \ne 0 \ne y$.

Comment: @user254665 When $xy^H=0$ with nonzero $x$ and $y$?